# Web Developer Tools option must be installed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have been working with Visual Studio Ultimate 2013. Today when I tried to open a solution, it tried to convert the solution and showed me error like

```
"The Web Developer Tools option must be installed prior to opening or creating Web projects. You can install this option by repairing your Microsoft Visual Studio installation and ensuring that 'Web Developer Tools' is checked in the list of optional components."
```

I goggled about this and tried to Modify the Visual Studio 2013 ultimate by enabling the Web Developer Tool. But here I am getting the other error like

```
Unable to Locate Package Source.
```

What should I do now?

Answer (score 70):

1. Go to Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Select your Visual Studio Version and hit "Change"
2. Click MODIFY and enable Web Developer Tools
3. Enable Web Developer Tools
4. Click Update

Comment: This should be marked as answer. I had the same problem and this fixed it.

Comment: If you have both Visual Studio 2015 and 2013 installed, make sure you apply the solution described above on Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: I have a similar problem in Visual Studio 2015. I unistalled it a couple of months back, and now after doing a full reinstall, with Web Developer Tools enabled, I cannot create ASP.NET sites. In New Project, there is no option for C# -> Web, and when I click New Website, the error above comes up. I tried disabling all optional addons with the installer, rebooted, then re-enabled all options and rebooted after the three hour setup procedure. I still have the same problem. Uninstalling and reinstalling makes no difference either. Is my only option to reimage a fresh Windows install?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the installer file for Visual Studio was deleted and is no longer available to modify installations.  If you can't locate it, you could just re-install Visual Studio, but that takes awhile.